# How to update json type column value in mysql if I have multi array on the json string

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json string and I want to edit value of college key in the json. The json string given below which is normally a column value from mysql table.

So my sql query :- select subjectcombination from table where id = 10;

```
subjectcombination = {"subjectcombination": [{"college": "GOVT. COLLEGE FOR BOYS, REWARI", "district": "REWARI", "college_uuid": "2C533FD3546CF32D2D8D057480006BEE", "district_uuid": "914B62192C43EFB8AA203EF848054856", "course_section": "B.A  I", "college_course_id": "28010"}]}
```

So Please let me know how can I update value of subjectcombination column value with specific college key(I want to update college value). For eg. :- update GOVT. COLLEGE FOR BOYS, REWARI to "ABC"

Comment: try this update TABLE set subjectcombination = JSON_SET(subjectcombination, "$.college", "ABC") where id = 10;

Comment: @Prany, Thanks for the answer but It's not updating value of college under the subjectcombination array. It updating like that :-

{"college": "ABC", "subjectcombination": [{"college": "GOVT. COLLEGE FOR BOYS, REWARI", "district": "REWARI", "college_uuid": "2C533FD3546CF32D2D8D057480006BEE", "district_uuid": "914B62192C43EFB8AA203EF848054856", "course_section": "B.A  I", "college_course_id": "28010"}]}

Comment: @Prany, It should be like :-
 {"subjectcombination": [{"college": "ABC", "district": "REWARI", "college_uuid": "2C533FD3546CF32D2D8D057480006BEE", "district_uuid": "914B62192C43EFB8AA203EF848054856", "course_section": "B.A I", "college_course_id": "28010"}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`JSON_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET subjectcombination = JSON_REPLACE(subjectcombination, '$.subjectcombination[0].college', 'ABC') 
WHERE id = 10;
```

You can also try the following `SELECT` to get a preview of the `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE(subjectcombination, '$.subjectcombination[0].college', 'ABC') 
FROM table_name;
```